# The correct architecture: How to deliver an array of custom objects

Tags: iphone, model-view-controller

Another architecture question.

I have a custom class calle Airfield. Let's say it has 2 ivars, name and tower frequency.
It's in a class called Airfield with a .h and .m file.

Problem is, I want to read a whole bunch of airfields from an XML file and give them to a controller for a table view.

Should I create a new class called airfielddb which imports airfield for the single object definition and reads the XML creating an array of airfield objects?

Or do I declare an array as an ivar in Airfield.h?

I am really struggling with some of these OO Modeling type questions. Your help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Neither of this. 
You should keep Airfield class as is- it's your model.
There  is no need in creating AirfieldDB class as well. You are loading data for tableview, and then you should implement the loading in your class implementing **UITableViewDataSource**
which could be possibly your ViewController.
You can also check the nice example at:
[Apple's Table view Programming guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/CreateConfigureTableView/CreateConfigureTableView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH6-SW5)(listing 4-6)

Comment: Thanks for the reply.But I don't want to reread the Airfield XML each time. I need something to persist across all potential UI elements of the app.

Comment: Well, then i'd go with airfieldDB or any other DataCenter(containing other data as well)